# How to find changepoints in data in python

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have lots of files that their plot looks like this:

[image]

and I want to find the changepoints in python and I can't find any proper package to do this correctly as fast as possible.
I worked with ruptures and changefinder packages but they didn't solve my problem.
This is the link of the file I'm trying to find changepoints  (which is separated with comma) and the sampling rate is 1000 Hz
[txt File of above image](https://gofile.io/d/NQWoNj)

in other words, I want to find the index of array elements which corresponds to red lines in the below picture:[image]

Comment: what do you mean by a changepoint? could you elaborate? for example, how many changepoints does the image above have?

Comment: could you please provide the code for ruptures or changefinder?

Comment: @armamut I mean rapid changes in signal or in other words sudden rising or falling. e.g. above pic has 18 changepoints

Comment: @RafaelValero the problem is that I can not give all of the signal to it (because of the memory problem), also I don't know which method of raptures fits best to my data.
Should I use windowing for the signal?

Comment: The ideal will be to have a sample of the real data.

Comment: What do you think is a change? In that particular case looks like you could actually create a simple algorithm, in line with windowing.

Comment: @RafaelValero, I edited my question to explain better the question

Comment: Please read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more on the on-topic questions for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
def avg(listi):
    s = 0
    for i in listi:
        s += i
    return s / len(listi)

def chunk(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

file = open('test.txt', 'r')
list_of_numbers = [float(x.strip()) for x in file.readline().split(',')]
file.close()


chunk_size = 100
chunks = list(chunk(list_of_numbers, chunk_size))
diff_treshold = 0.1
last_chunk_avg = avg(chunks[0])
i = 0
cnt = 0
changepoints = []
for chunki in chunks:
    this_chunk_avg = avg(chunki)
    if abs(this_chunk_avg - last_chunk_avg) > diff_treshold:
        # print(int((i * chunk_size) + (chunk_size / 2)))
        changepoints.append(int((i * chunk_size) + (chunk_size / 2)))
        cnt += 1
    i += 1
    last_chunk_avg = this_chunk_avg

print("Count of changepoints: ", cnt)
print("Changepoints: ", changepoints)
```

I've got this output for your file:

```
Count of changepoints:  20
Changepoints:  [20550, 39050, 39150, 44750, 44850, 52650, 52750, 57550, 57650, 71850, 71950, 81050, 81150, 90250, 90350, 105950, 106050, 119550, 125150, 125250]
```

you can change `chunk_size` and `diff_treshold` to adjust the sensitivity to changes